# Problema con grid-gap y fr

Tags: css, grid, css-grid-layout

Estoy en un problema algo tonto, tengo dos `section` `grid`, el cual el primero tiene 4 `div` con la propiedad `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` y el segundo `section` tiene 3 `div` con la propiedad `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;` es decir el div del centro tiene 2fr a diferencia de sus hermanos de los lados con `1fr`. Lo que necesito es que los div de ambos section se alineen verticalmente y sean del mismo tamaño, es decir, los div de `1f` sean del mismo `ancho`.

Aunque ambos `section` tienen el mismo `grid-gap: 20px;` aun asi queda una pequeña diferencia de espaciado y tamaño.

Creo que el problema esta en el `grid-gap`que le estoy pasando, pero realmente estoy confundida no se como calcular, para lograr lo necesario.

Agradezco la ayuda.

```css
section{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.section1{
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
.section2{
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
section > div {
  background: #faf;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>


<section class="section2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: El tema es que en el primer section tienes tres espacio y en el segundo solo dos por lo que hay 20px de diferencia en el espacio a repartir .No creo que se puedan alinear usando unidades `fr`

Comment: Otra opción seria que en lugar de dos `grid` tuvieras solo uno, entonces la rejilla sería igual para todos los `div` y te encajarían.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en el primer section el hay 3 huecos de 20px y en el segundo solo 2, utilizando `fr` siempre quedarán 20px en el aire.

Lo que puedes hacer es forzar en `px` la segunda columna del segundo section para que cuadre bien.

```
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 240px 1fr;
```

```css
section{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;  
}
.section1{
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
.section2{  
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 240px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
section > div {
  background: #faf;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>


<section class="section2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: estupendo veo que funciona, cual seria la formula a utilizar para calcular cuantos px darle al div grande del segundo section? lo he conseguido en mi proyecto real haciéndolo con % pero digamos que probando poco a poco, no con algo exacto. Gracias!

Comment: Es sencillo, tienes que saber lo que mide un div pequeño, para ello con darle click derecho e inspeccionar aparece, luego lo multiplicas por 2 y le añades el grid-gap, en este caso son 110px * 2 + 20px = 240px

Answer (score 1):

En su momento pensé que no podía hacerse de forma dinámica pero era tan secillo como poner un porcentaje en la columna del centro. Como en el grid superior tienes 4 columnas necesitas una columna que ocupe la mitad, un 50%.

Sigue habiendo un pequeño desfase porque en el grid superior tienes 3 espacios entre columnas y en el de abajo solo dos, la solución es usar `calc` y restarle esa diferencia, en este caso 10px. Pongo el `section` en porcentajes para que se vea que aunque cambie de tamaño se mantienen alineadas las columnas:

```css
section{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.section1{
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
.section2{
  grid-template-columns: 1fr calc(50% - 10px) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
section > div {
  background: #faf;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>


<section class="section2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```